# pytesseract Failed loading language \'eng\'

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've seen a lot of other people getting this error, and I've tried a lot of different things to fix it. Nothing so far has worked. I have:

- Added the path to my Tesseract-OCR folder AND the tesseract.exe file to PATH
- Added an environment variable called TESSDATA_PREFIX which leads to the Tesseract-OCR folder
- Replaced the eng.traneddata file a couple times
- Added `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"` to the program
- Tried running JUST [the quickstart file](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract#usage) instead of the program I'm running it in

and nothing has changed the error. At this point, I'm just looking for anything. The full error is as follows.

```
  File "pytesseract should work please.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('text.png')))
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 309, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 308, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 218, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 194, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

Comment: `TESSDATA_PREFIX` should lead to the folder with traineddata files (eg eng.traineddata)

Comment: Really? In the error it says `Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.`. I did switch it, and it still didnt fix it or change the error.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is tessdata, not traineddata folder. I wanted to point out that it might not be your "Tesseract-OCR" folder as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by fully uninstalling pytesseract and installing an older version (3.2? I think..). So far I haven't noticed any functionality loss. I'm personally just happy that it works.

Answer (score -1):

try these steps:
step1: Change this path using '/' instead of '\'. e.g., from ==>
**[1]: pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"**

to

**[1]: pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"**

step2: configure to TESSDATA_PREFIX environment using==>

**[2]: tessdata_dir_config = r'--tessdata-dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata"'**

step3:text==>

**[3]: pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('text.png'),lang='eng',config=tessdata_dir_config)**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please fix the formatting on this; it's quite hard to read.  Use code blocks on code, an extra blank line between paragraphs, etc.